# How to install cs-script on Mac properly

Tags: c#, macos, sublimetext3, cs-script

I installed cs-script from [here](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script-sublime) on my Mac (using High Sierra) manually. I want to use it for [SublimeText v3](http://www.sublimetext.com/). The plugin loads - so far so good.

The problem is that when I try to execute my code with cs-script nothing happens.

The documentation [here](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script-sublime/wiki/Installing-plugin-on-OS-X) tells me that I have to change the path to mono since the [Mono-framework](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/mac/) has now been installed at /Library/Frameworks/mono.framework and is now at a different location.

The documentation says "If mono cannot be located the "about output" (above) will be truncated and consist of only two first lines [...]".
When I click the About-menu of cs-script I can see the first two lines and nothing else (this means it's not working).

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script-sublime/wiki/Installing-plugin-on-OS-X) I changed the path in the file cs-script.sublime-settings to the following:

```
{
    "last_run_version": "1.2.8",
    "mono_path": "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/bin/mono"
}
```

But it's still not working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) when you try to run a script and nothing happens?

Comment: Indeed there is an error message: "Cannot configure syntaxer server with cscs location. Schedule another attempt in 3 seconds.
TypeError: try_send_cscs_path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cscs_path'"